# Call method Dynamically based on param in Scala

Tags: scala

i have on class bellow in scala

```
 class A(arg:String){

 // this method is going to call many time 
 def exce():String ={
 // i do not want to use if else here
 if("arg"=="a1")
 a1("abc")
 if("arg"=="a1")
  a2("abc")
 }
 def a1(arg1:String):String={
 "in a1"
 }
 def a2(arg1:String):String={
 "in a2"
 }
 }
```

I will create instance of class A and will pass arg value as method name now 
    how can i call method "exce",and exce method will call a1 or a2 based on args
    like 
    new A("a1").exce()  -- output will be a1
    how can achieve this without using if else in "exce" method

can some one help here

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood it correctly .I think this would solve your use case :

```
class A(arg:String){
  def exce():String = arg match{
    case "a1"=>a1("abc")
    case "a2"=>a2("abc")
  }

  def a1(arg1:String):String={
    "in a1"
  }
  def a2(arg1:String):String={
    "in a2"
  }
}
```

Now when you call `new A("a1").exec()`
Then it gives `in a1`

Comment: it will problem but here if i will call a1 million times it will million times in case statement i was looking something where

Comment: it will problem but here if i will call a1 million times it will million times in case statement i was looking something where  val obj= new A("a1") and obj.exe() now exec should logic it should detect method name while instantiating class A and when i will call exce million time it already know which method need to call and no need to go in case every time

Answer (score 1):

First of all your methods `a1,a2,exec` are public but why you want to have indirect way of calling like `exec()->a1() or a2()` ? .I assume that you missed to add private to `a1` and `a2`. if `exec` method is going to be called many times then you should pass your method name as exec(name:String).Meaning *you have to create new A instance if you going to call new method*.  Pattern matching would be your alternative to if-else

```
class A{

  private def a1(arg1: String): String = {
    "in a1"
  }
  private def a2(arg1: String): String = {
    "in a2"
  }

  def exec(funName: String): String = {

    funName match {
 //You can think about passing input param "abc" from caller as well.
      case "a1" => a1("abc")
      case "a2" => a2("abc")
    }

  }

}

object Main extends App {

val a =new A()
println(a.exec("a1"))
println(a.exec("a2"))

}
```

**Result :**

> in a1
>
> in a2

Alternatively you can make your **args as val** if don't wish to pass it as method param

```
    class  A(val args:String){
    
    // your a1,a2 methods goes here

 def exec(): String = {

    args match {
 //You can think about passing input param "abc" from caller as well.
      case "a1" => a1("abc")
      case "a2" => a2("abc")
    }
    }
    
    object Main extends App {
    
    val a =new A("a1")
    println(a.exec())
    a.args = "a2"
    println(a.exec())
    
    }
```

**Result :**

> in a1
>
> in a2